# Validacion con mensaje personalizado en Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

intento realizar una validación personalizada en Livewire y no puedo obtener el resultado deseado, probé la siguiente funcionalidad:

```
$this->validate([

    ['search' => 'required'],
    [
        'search.required' => 'El campo buscador obligatorio',
    ],

]);
```

Este proceso lo encontré en la documentación pero no me funciona, recibo el siguiente error:

> Exception
> No property found for validation: [0]

Agradezco mucho una mano en este tema. Gracias por destinar tiempo en mi consulta!

Comment: Hola! gracias, Uso Livewire, no utilizo el $request sino $this. Los valores los paso por la propiedad.

Comment: Ya veo, el problema en si esta porque estas poniendo doble `[]` ya que pones `$this->validate("["   ['search'],['search.required']   "]")`